# How to check existing of snapshot if you use ChildEventListener?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In firebase, I try to use `ChildEventListener`. But in some cases, the snapshot that I am looking for, does not exist. If there is no snapshot, child event listener's method is not called even. I found that to check the existing of a snapshot, I need to use `ValueEventListener`. But it is not convenient for to use ValueEventListener for checking and after to use ChildEventListener. So, is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `if(dataSnapshot.exists()` with ValueEventListener or SingleValueEvent, it cannot be used with ChildEventListener.

But if you want to use `ChildEventListener` then nest it inside a `ValueEventListener`

Example:

```
 mRootRef.child("user").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

         //add childeventlistener here

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: This will download everything twice

Comment: Indeed but this is the only solution to the question. Another solution is to change the structure of the database so you don't download everything twice. But no structure was even provided in the original question :/

Comment: I guess you're right, what I ended up with is, I only downloaded a single item of a list to check it (`.limitToFirst(1) ... exists()`). If it's not a list, you but in this case a user, you can check it with a single child that cannot be empty if the user exists, possibly with as little content as possible, e.g. `.child('username') ... exists()`

Comment: Sure, I know. I need the ChildEventlistener, it's a Chatting Application. I need the ValueEventListener to check if there are any messages yet in a certain chat. Downvote because a user object can be huge, e.g. Biography, all kind of stats, etc. Downloading that twice will be expensive in production

Comment: You need to put the chatting between two users on one node and the user info in another node on its own. That why you only retrieve the conversation of the two users without retrieving other stuff that are not relevant